# How to use a postgresql trigger to set a UUID

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, uuid

I have a table called `students` that gets populated from an external source. The data comes in w/ composite keys that I then want to use to generate a UUID via `uuid_generate_v5`. I'm currently doing this via

```
UPDATE students SET id = uuid_generate_v5(uuid_ns_url(), CONCAT(composite1, composite2));
```

I'm interested in moving this into a trigger whenever a row gets inserted into this table. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Create a `before insert or update on students` trigger. [Docs are here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html). (Scroll down for examples.) Whether you need this rather than just `before insert on students` is application-dependent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like the untested:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_trigger() 
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
   NEW.uuid_col := uuid_generate_v5(uuid_ns_url(), CONCAT(NEW.composite1, NEW.composite2));
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger();
```

but really, [the manual on PL/PgSQL triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) and [the `CREATE TRIGGER` docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) should really get you there...

Comment: The syntax for the function part was really tripping me up. Thanks for this!